# How to select values that have 1:1 indexes in a datataframe with multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a multi-index an I want to select only those rows whose indexes are 1:1

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one' ])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 4), index=arrays)
```

I expect to select only

```
qux one -0.521636 -2.253847 -0.420486 1.354772
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need remove duplicated rows by first level of `MultiIndex` with [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
                0         1         2         3
qux one -1.031044 -0.838885  0.316934  0.353254
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with any column - e.g. first (or you can specify it) for counts per first level:

```
df = df[df.groupby(level=0)[df.columns[0]].transform('size').eq(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, does it make sense to also include df.loc[(~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)) & ((~df.index.get_level_values(1).duplicated(keep=False)) ] ?

Comment: @reydonsancho - just tested and `df = df.loc[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False) | ~df.index.get_level_values(1).duplicated(keep=False) ]` working too, but in my opinion test by first level working same.